Why did the writers of Pokémon decide that Pikachu shouldn't go in the Poké Ball?
Anyone who knows the Pokémon show has probably seen the first episode, in which it's shown that Pikachu will not go in his Poké Ball. It's last brought up for a gag in the episode, and then for the rest of the series, Pikachu is never in the ball (apparently it gets brought up in one of the recent films, where Ash just says "he doesn't like it").
But why did the writers do this? The naive/easy answer is that they just did it because it was funny, but they then committed to it for the next 25 seasons when they could have easily undone it in the first episode. You could also argue that keeping him out of the ball helps solidify him as the mascot of the series, but when the show was originally written in 1996/97, that wasn't the intention. Surely there's an alternate reason for this.

Because they wanted to sell plush toys to children


You could also argue that keeping him out of the ball helps solidify him as the mascot of the series, but when the show was originally written in 1996/97 wasn't the intention.

I am wrong. Apparently, it wasn't even the anime staff who chose Pikachu; it was the Pokemon executives who went with it before the anime was made. So this was actually the intention.
I found several sources for this, but they all seem to be consolidated in a forum post on Elite Fourum. The forum post offers a few editorial reasons why, but it also links to an MTV article with a quote from Junichi Masuda, a programmer on the Pokemon series and an executive at GameFreak and The Pokémon Company:

Of course, Pokemon ended up being a massive hit worldwide, and the franchise quickly adopted an unlikely figurehead: an electric mouse named Pikachu. I say unlikely because, in the first two games, Pikachu was just another random Pokemon milling around in the weeds. Later entries, like "Pokemon Yellow," would heavily feature Pikachu, but I was curious whether Pikachu initially stood out from the pack during the development phase, and if Masuda expected him to be such a huge hit. Here's how the world-famous electric mouse came to be:
"In the beginning, we had a few graphic designers working on drawing designs, coming up with ideas. We also had a few programmers who also came up with design ideas. Within the company, we would vote and decide which one everyone likes. One of the planners saw Pikachu and was like, 'This is a really cute Pokemon. Maybe it's not a good idea to have it be a really common Pokemon in the game.' It was a Pokemon he just wanted to catch, just for himself. [The fact that Pikachu] is a rare Pokemon that doesn't show up very often in the wild was another reason [he was popular]. When people actually encountered it, it was a really big impact. It was like, 'Wow, this is a cool Pokemon.' At the same time, in the animation, Ash had Pikachu as his Pokemon, so those two things combined helped the popularity of Pikachu rise."


Possibly related on Anime.SE: Why was Pikachu chosen to be the main Pokemon of the anime?

The quote does not say anything about what the question is asking.

@OrangeDog I think the key takeaway is that the people at Game Freak saw Pikachu as special ("cool" and "cute") early on. And this led to the decision to showcase Pikachu by keeping it out of its Poké Ball in the anime.

@galacticninja but "this led to" is entirely speculation

@OrangeDog I see your point. While it's not explicitly stated, Masuda's quote about Pikachu being "really cute" and not wanting it to be a "common Pokemon" hints at the special treatment it received. It's not a big leap to connect this to Pikachu staying out of its Poké Ball in the anime.
